# C# GUI moving past the basics, anyone with some good guides to the framework

Tags: c#, user-interface

I have worked with the C# framework a while now via Visual Express, and liked how easy it was to add GUI and work from there (event driven from the user on fixed fields).

But I am now starting to need more complex things, and could use some good guides to understand the framework better. When I search for guides, I end up with newbie guides that shows how to add a component, setup event handler etc. All the stuff I already know.

I am a novice coder in terms of the GUI, I simply do not understand the framework, in fact I know so little beside drag and drop, that I do not know what keywords to search for to find the answers I need. So I would like to understand the framework better, so I can help myself. The following examples are issues I have run into that I have been unable to research an answer for as I simply do not know what to look for

I hope someone can either let me know what to search for to get into this framework, or even better link some guides they can recommend to read up on it.

***How do I update the GUI from a worker thread?**

What is the best approach here, my failed attempts so far include pushing directly to the label but I am told it is not allowed due to synchronization. I can see how this would be an issue if two different threads push updates at the same time. How should I go about this.

***How do I add additional fields/forms**

Here I load some data from a server, which might have 0 to N entries, I would like this to populate a box with buttons, 1 for each answer. I have no clue how to get these added to the box. (eg. friendslist)

***How do I add an array of components in the best way**

I would like to add say for examples sake a chessboard to the GUI, 8x8 fields. Adding those manually 1 at a time and updating them, making them all use the same event handler would be tedious, so how would I tie code similar to this so it gets added to the form

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8;i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        holderComponent.Add(CreateTile());
    }
    holderComponent.NewLine();
}

Private SomeKindOfComponentUsedFor Tiles CreateTile()
{
    <some kind of code that creates the tile, ties the listener on click etc to the tile component>
    return generatedComponent;
}
```

***How do I create a separate window**

I might want a popup to my program, and have a separate window designed for it, how do I code it, start it as a new thread, and communicate between the two in the best way.

---

Again I am not looking for the specific answers to these problems which should be trivial problems (once you understand the framework), but instead links/keywords so I can figure out what I am searching for to learn what is going on, and how it all ties together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really get a book or take a class to get a complete understanding of this. The answers I've provided below will surely lead to more questions. Entire volumes have been written about such subjects.

> How do I update the GUI from a worker thread?

Pretty much every GUI component that comes with the framework derives from the [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx) class, which exposes a methods called [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke.aspx), [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Control.BeginInvoke.aspx), and [EndInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.endinvoke.aspx). These methods are some of the very few GUI-class methods that can be called safely from a worker thread. These methods cause the passed-in method or delegate to be called on the UI thread, from which you can safely update the GUI. Another way, which doesn't involve creating your own worker thread, is to use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), which will raise an event on the UI thread when the background thread is complete.

> How do I add additional fields/forms

The base Control class also has a collection property called [Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx). Not every derived Control type will support this, but Forms, Panels, etc, will. You can dynamically modify this collection to produce controls at runtime.

```
myForm.Controls.Clear();
myForm.Controls.Add(new CheckBox());
myForm.Controls.Add(new CheckBox());
myForm.Controls.Add(new CheckBox());
```

> How do I add an array of components in the best way

WPF/Silverlight/WindowsPhone apps arguably have the best way of doing this. The base [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) class in those frameworks is designed specifically to take a collection and produce a dynamic number of UI elements. Derived classes like ListBox, ComboBox, etc, provide ItemsControl implementations that operate certain ways, but you can use ItemsControl directly to produce you own dynamic content. WPF has a pretty steep learning curve.

For WinForms, there's no equivalent. You would just use the Controls collection to manually build up the controls you need, as shown in the previous example. Depending on what type of container (Form, TableLayoutPanel, etc) you're using, you may need to set the location and size properties correctly to make sure the resulting controls are positioned and sized correctly.

> How do I create a separate window

You don't typically start a new thread for a new window. Read up on message pumps in Windows, which are core to the entire windowing technology in any Windows-based framework (Visual C++, .NET, etc, etc). You typically just design a form, then instantiate it and either call [Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show.aspx) (returns immediately) or [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog.aspx) (doesn't return until the form is closed, useful for dialogs [message-box type windows]).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to go into such details. Things are already starting to become clearer for me. I would love to read a book/guide about this, but I have no idea of which to get, what is worthwhile, which is part of the reason I added this question. The guides I found all told good basic stuff, but has all been sparse on details of how the framework works (most likely as the audience they were targeted at would not benefit from the information). Quick followup question, the "CheckBox" you refer to in this example and most other GUI component, what collection "using" should I add?